# AngularJs If/Else in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a dynamic elements in template with angularjs,but while creating i need to check some datas  ,therefore i want to use if else in template to create needed datas.When i use it like my code it gives errors.

My directive;

```
app.directive('myfunc', [
'$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
restrict: 'E',
controller: function($scope) {.......},
template:"<div class='myclass'> "+if(data=='something'){+"<input type='checkbox'>"+}+"</div>" , .............
```

How can i create needed elements with if else in template?

Comment: you could use ng-show / ng-hide

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if` directive. Alternatively `ng-show` and `ng-hide`. In case you need further logic I would highly recommend putting this extra logic in js code which would be controller, service or directive itself. Another option is using templateUrl: function()... where you can have logic to use a specific template